# How to run JavaScript code as soon <body> element is defined?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document-body

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    console.log('test')
  </script>

  <p>
    Foo
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to move the JavaScript in this code from `<body>` into `<head>`. Here is my incorrect attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Foo</title>
  <script>
  window.onload = function () {
    console.log('test')
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>
    Foo
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

This of course does not do what I want. It runs the JavaScript only after the whole page has loaded. But I want the JavaScript to run as soon as `<body>` is defined. Can this be done in JavaScript?

Comment: [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)?

Comment: You may want to check out arrive.js. I'm not an expert in it myself, but it is a library that uses many techniques to run code when an element loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert your log command into a defined Javascript function at the **`<head>`** part of your Html and call this function soon after the opening of **`<body>`**.

Your final code will look this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function myFunction(){
  console.log('test');
}
</script>

<title>Foo</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
  myFunction();
</script>

<p>
Foo
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

It's worth to mention that the **onload** event-property do exists in another html tags too, and only on those cases it is executed right after it's definition, which means: immediately.

With **`<body>`** tag happens something singular: the **onload** only runs after two conditions:

**1)** the express definition of **`</body>`**;

**2)** the finishing of the loading of all accessory and maybe external routines and resources, which means: the loading of all html, css, jpg, gif, svg etc.

So, the **onload** do what it promises: runs **when and only after** page 100% loaded.

Comment: Thank you @Lone Learner.